# How to display pixels 1:1 in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I have a bitmap (from a .bmp file) that is actually a small part of a larger screen dump that I took earlier.

Now I want to display that bitmap in a PictureBox control (WinForms), but I have trouble getting it to display at the same ratio as when it was captured originally.

I assume it has something to do with Windows' DPI setting for my monitor, but how can I shortcut that and make the bitmap be displayed exactly as when captured?

Comment: SizeMode AutoSize or SizeMode Normal;

Comment: I already tried that, but the image is still displayed considerably larger than the original screen dump... :-(

Comment: Sounds like you're on a high-DPI display and your application isn't DPI-aware, correct? :)

Comment: I think you are right... and?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The problem was not WinForms, but the horizontal and vertical resolution associated with the displayed bitmap. When copying the part of the original screendump into a new bitmap (the one that is later assigned to the Image property of the PictureBox), the new bitmap had a different (=default) resolution setting. By changing the resolution setting to match the one from the source bitmap (the original screendump), the problem went away!